# How can I build a web app that I can send files to for further manipulation?

Tags: node.js

I want to build a NodeJS server that accepts a .wav file (1Mb) sent to its single endpoint, then changes the file through AudioContext API and then sends back the response with the result?
The server shouldn't store anything, so, no database required.
How can I achieve this? (or, please correct me if don't understand how things work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with express: https://expressjs.com/
and as middleware add express-fileuplaod: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

```js
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files.foo); // the uploaded file object
});
```

instead of the console.log(); you'd make a readable stream / buffer and then use it in the 
AudioContext API

here is also a interesting Article explaining to use this:
https://www.russellgood.com/process-uploaded-file-web-audio-api/